# Hudson - capturing logs from slaves

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I have MASTER and SLAVE configured (ssh-slave-plugin).

I would like to display output of the slave executed script under job on master, 
as so far I get

```
Building remotely on SubAgent
Triggering SubAgent
Triggering a new build of XXXX #126
Finished: SUCCESS
```

and that is all. So the whole execution is hidden.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using the same master-slave configuration (ssh) on Hudson and all the logs are visible on the Hudson Interface.
There might be a couple of things that you can check:

1. What tool are you using to build (eg, ANT, MAVEN...). Check the execution if the logs are being produced at all
2. Check the **Console Output [raw]**
3. Manage Hudson > Manage Nodes > Select the Slave > Configure

   - Make Sure that "Remote FS root" is mentioned.
   - Check **Launch Method**. I am Connecting to my slaves via **jnlp** (*I believe this could be the key*)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Nodes, choose the node (or hover on the name) and select Build History. The logs of the job that ran on the slave node will be there.